# Vue 3 - How to execute a function on binding instance in custom directive

Tags: vue.js

Im creating a custom directive as follows in main.ts .

```
let handleOutsideClick: any;
app.directive("closable", {
  mounted: (el, binding, vnode) => {
    handleOutsideClick = (e: any) => {
      e.stopPropagation();

      const payload = binding.value;

      console.log(`instance: ${Object.getOwnPropertyNames(binding.instance)}`);
    };

    document.addEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
  },
  unmounted: (el) => {
    document.removeEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
  },
});
```

Inside the event handler i want to make a call to a function on the component that triggered this directive.

With Vue 2 you could do it with vnode.context'myfunction' but this does not seem to work with binding.instance.

How can i call the function using the binding instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing the function to be called as the binding's value and then calling it seems to work:

```js
if (typeof binding.value === 'function') {
  binding.value()
}
```

Working example:

```js
const { createApp } = Vue;

const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    return { test: () => console.log('here') }
  }
})

app.component('demo', {
  template: `<div>test</div>`
})

let handleOutsideClick;
app.directive("closable", {
  mounted: (el, binding, vnode) => {
    handleOutsideClick = (e) => {
      e.stopPropagation();

      const payload = binding.value;

      console.log(`instance: ${Object.getOwnPropertyNames(binding.instance)}`);
      if (typeof binding.value === 'function') {
        binding.value()
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
  },
  beforeUnmount: (el) => {
    document.removeEventListener("click", handleOutsideClick);
  },
});

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.41/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <demo v-closable="test"></demo>
</div>
```

---

Notes:

- vue internal method names change based on environment. For example, if you remove `.prod` from the vue link in the example above, you'll get more data out of `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(binding.instance)`.
  If your app's business logic relies on vue internals method naming:
    **a)** you're *doing it wrong™*;
    **b)** it won't work in production
- if the above is not helpful, please provide more details on your specific use-case via a *runnable* [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
  If you need a multi-file node-like online editor, note codesandbox.io allows [importing](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli) local projects using their CLI utility.

Comment: Thank you! Yeah the getOwnPropertyNames was just me trying to ferret out what the available properties and/or functions were. How did you find the information for this? I spent a couple hours trying to figure this out, it took me forever just to find out to replace vnode.context with binding.instance, which i accidentally found on the migration guide. Is there some more thorough documentation out there somewhere? It doesnt seem to be on the official Vue website unless im being blind. How would i find like a msdn/mozilla level documentation for the binding object?

Comment: I approached it a bit differently. You were trying to find out how to migrate some code from v2 to v3. I only looked at the functionality and asked myself: what's the simplest way to get it done in Vue3? Tried passing + calling the function. It worked. What helped me most was the fact you explained what the goal of the code was.

Comment: I'm not sure calling the function is called with the correct context (e.g: with the correct `this`). That's not a problem in Composition API, because it doesn't rely on `this`, but if you do need it, you'll need to pass it to the function and use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) or [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).